# Type-safe collection of Type class with defined base type

Tags: c#

I'm use generic collection in my code:

```
List<Type>
```

what I really want is to get type-safe collection of types with defined basetype
something like `List<typeof(BaseType)>`, but valid :)

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Could you give a fuller example?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Do you want a list of `Type` objects, where `Type` represents either a runtime type of `BaseType` or a type derived from `BaseType` (where the type is obtained from `typeof()` or `object.GetType()`?

Comment: I'm actually use Queue to store Types of classes and create instances of this classes with reflection as this: `(Page)Activator.CreateInstance(Pages[CurrentPage], this); `. I had to do this, because this types should be initialized in the moment of creation

Comment: If I understand you are trying to create objects for initialization, then I would suggest use IOC containers/MEF that can do this for you.

Comment: It is perfectly clear what @Deadcow is asking - I just found this because I'm trying to do exactly the same thing. They want a list of Types and they want those Types constrained to only be for objects with a certain base type. In my case I'm trying to build up a list of types to include in a schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a type-safe collection of `Type` objects that describe types that derive from a base type, because C#'s type-safe generic mechanism can only operate on types known at compile-time, while the relationship between a `typeof(MyBaseType)` and a `typeof(MyDerivedType)` are only knowm at runtime.

Furthermore, you have to remember that the relationship between these `Type` objects is not actually a relationship of inheritance. `string` may derive from `object`, but `typeof(string)` doesn't derive from `typeof(object)`. So while their relationship may seem to be relevant to type-safety, it isn't really.

A collection of `Type` objects of subtypes of a specific type is equivalent, in terms of type safety, to a collection of even-numbered `int`s only - it has nothing to do with type safety, and as such would be difficult to implement with generics.

Comment: I'm actually believed there is no way to do this and just wanted to be sure. There is a nice `IsSubclassOf` method of `Type` class and there was a chance that compiler may use it to ensure type safety of `Type` :)

Comment: `IsSubclassOf()` is a runtime method. It's no different than having an `IsEven()` method on an int. It's not a feature of the type system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you really understand what a `Type` really is.

`Type` is a class that describes a runtime type (it's fields, properties, methods, events and so on), but other than that there is no real difference in type between `typeof(TDerived)` and `typeof(TBase)`.

If you just want a list that can store references to both `TBase` and `TDerived` instances - you can simply declare:

```
List<TBase> myList;
```

If you just want a list that stores references to `Type` instances - you simply declare a `List<Type>` as you have already done - in this list you can place any `Type` reference - e.g. `typeof(int)`, `typeof(TBase)` etc.

Comment: I want to store Types of classes and create instances of this classes later for some reason. Now I must check instance type after it's creation and I want to reach type safety with Collection instance declaration

Comment: just use static analysis of the type before adding it to the collection. I.E `if(type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TBase)))`