# Collection of types which implement a specific interface

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a class with the name ForumHolderAdminController. ForumHolderAdminController provides a collection of controller types to the parent class CmsAdminController.

I have the following code:

```
public abstract class CmsAdminController : Controller {
    // The type of child controllers allowed
    protected Collection<Type> AllowedChildren {
        get { return null; }
    }
}

public class ForumHolderAdminController : CmsAdminController {
    protected new Collection<Type> AllowedChildren {
        get {
            Collection<Type> allowedChildren = new Collection<Type> {
                typeof(ThreadHolderController)
            };
            return allowedChildren;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to restrict developers to passing a collection of types that implement the IController interface. Something similar to the following:

```
protected new Collection<IController> AllowedChildren {
        get {
            Collection<IController> allowedChildren = new Collection<IController> {
                typeof(ThreadHolderController)
            };
            return allowedChildren;
        }
    }
```

Obviously the code example won't work because there is no instance being created. But I would like something similar to this where you don't have to create an instance of an object, you just have to pass the type.

I did see the following question which appears to be somewhat relevant, however one of the comments suggests using static analysis of the type before adding it to the collection:
[Type-safe collection of Type class with defined base type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827835/type-safe-collection-of-type-class-with-defined-base-type)

If I have to perform a static analysis this leaves me with a problem. If the developer passes a type that hasn't implemented the IController interface we won't know there is a problem with the code until it is executed. I would prefer it there was a compile error preventing developers from passing a collection of types where one or more don't implement the IController interface.

Therefore, is it possible to restrict developers to passing a collection of types that implement the IController interface?

Comment: Your code doesn't have input parameters so it's hard to get what you mean by 'it possible to restrict developers to passing a collection of types that implement the IController interface'. Anyway it sounds like you can use generics with constrains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could come pretty close to what you want to do by returning a custom class that wraps the Type, and which can only be instantiated for generic types that implement IController:

```
public class ControllerTypeWrapper<T> : ControllerTypeWrapper
    where T : IController
{
    public Type Type {get {return typeof(T);}}
}

public class ControllerTypeWrapper
{
    // This should only be extended by ControllerTypeWrapper<T>
    internal ControllerTypeWrapper(){}
}
```

Then your `AllowedChildren property should return these wrappers, and whatever's consuming it can simply use the`.Type` property off of the results:

```
protected new IReadOnlyCollection<ControllerTypeWrapper> AllowedChildren {
   get {
       return new List<ControllerTypeWrapper> {
           new ControllerTypeWrapper<ThreadHolderController>()
       };
   }
}
```

> Note: You probably don't actually intend to have this property be `new`. Consider making the parent class's property `abstract` so you can force the child classes to `override` it.

Another option would be to use Alex Voskresenskiy's approach, with a `RegisterType<T>()` method, but in that case you probably want that method to be protected, and expect your child class's constructor to call into `RegisterType<>()` with whatever child types you want to allow. The down-side to this would be that you're doing this work every time the controller is constructed, whereas it's likely you only need it once.

There are likely other, even better, options, like using custom attributes and using a simple unit test to check that all the attributes on all your controllers have the appropriate types in them. But it's hard to say without knowing more about how you intend to use this data.

Comment: I did think about unit testing but I prefer this solution because it is a more reliable way to ensure the IController interface is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i got you right, but you can do something like this:

```
public abstract class CmsAdminController : Controller
{
    private Collection<Type> _allowedChildren = new Collection<Type>();
    // The type of child controllers allowed
    protected Collection<Type> AllowedChildren
    {
        get {return _allowedChildren; }
    }

    public void Registertype<T>() where T : IController
    {
        _allowedChildren.Add(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

The only thing you should also do is to restrict `Add` on _allowedChildren, for example you can return `IEnumerable` instead of `Collection`

Comment: I get the impression that the OP doesn't want to generate an instance in order to pass it in--he just wants to use `Type` data.

Comment: You should remove the `T type` from `RegisterType`. This signature adds the requirement of passing in an instance of the object, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense considering the method doesn't use the object at all.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior so what's the problem with RegisterType? :)

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy When I made that comment, you were requiring that an object be passed in, as Erik pointed out.